# Rails 4 : uninitialized constant User::Country

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relation

I have this error in my Rails 4 app:

```
uninitialized constant User::Country
```

else, I have not this error in my Rails 3 app.

I have a User model with "belongs_to :country".

The controller query is:

```
@records = User.where(conditions).includes(:country).order('id DESC').page(@page).per(PER_PAGE)
```

The view code is:

```
<% for record in @records %>
<td class="center" width="50"><%= image_tag("flags/#{record.country.image}") if !record.country.nil? %></td>
<% end %>
```

Really, I don't understand why Rails 4 doesn't understand the relation between User and Country !

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
end

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :users
end
```

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT: error snapshot**

[image]

GOT IT:
**The problem was a plugin I used in Rails 3 that surely break something for ActiveRecord in Rails 4.**

Comment: What file contains the definition of `Country` class?

Comment: The file is country.rb.

Comment: Where does the error point to?

Comment: It points to the <% for record in @records %> line. I added a snapshot in the main thread.

Comment: I can't see any problem here. Are you sure you didn't misspell something?

Comment: Hi Marek, you are right. I found the problem. It's a plugin I used in Rails 3: https://github.com/iulianu/rails-fuzzy-search

If I removed the 2 lines below in my country model, I have no errors:
include FuzzySearch
  fuzzy_search_attributes :name_en, :name_fr, :name_it, :name_es, :name_de

Sorry for that !